# two values in one field

Tags: php

I've this simple form, when the price is set to `120` $:

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="addon[book]" value="120" /> book
  <input type="checkbox" name="addon[plane]" value="420" /> Plane
```

Could I send two values (USD & €) with thr form?

**EDIT:**

I added `name="addon[book]"` because I'll display the `name` too

**EDIT 2:**

PHP:

```
foreach($addon as $name => $value) {
    echo 'your addons: '.$name;
}
$total = array_sum(array_map("intval", $_POST["addon"]));
echo 'the total '.$total.' $';
```

Comment: What do you want to do? Why not compute the value at the server side?

Comment: @Felix Kling I want to display two currency 
@Pushpendra OK

Comment: What if someone changed the price in html and sent `12` instead of `120`? Will the book be sold for `12E` price?

Comment: Are you aware that anybody can change the value you send with tools like Firebug? You don't want this to happen if this value is a price, do you?

Comment: Why do you use `input` elements for displaying? Please be more specific.

Comment: @Felix Kling NO I use PHP of course

Comment: @MiniNaim: don't send the value, send the id of your book.

Comment: @greg0ire  I'm using a simple form with HTML (without sql).

Comment: @MiniNaim: you don't need SQL (but it would be faaaar better) to check the id against an associative array an find the corresponding price.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<input type="hidden" name="addon[book_USD]" value="250" />
<input type="checkbox" name="addon[book_EUR]" value="120" /> book
```

However NEVER trust the input from the form. Check the price in the backend code or users can change the price!

EDIT

What about json encoding?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="addon[book]" value="{&quot;USD&quot;:250,&quot;EUR&quot;:120}" /> book
```

EDIT2

To explode the values you'll have to use `json_decode()`

EDIT3

As others (and myself) already stated what you are trying to do (at least from the looks of it) is that you use the price from the input field as the price the user is going to pay.

That is not the best thing you can do, cause users can easily change the price of the input field.

I don't know your code but somehting like the following would be much better:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="addon[book]" value="book1">
```

And in your PHP code:

```
$prices = array('book1'=>array('USD'=>250, 'EUR'=>120),
                'book2'=>array('USD'=>120, 'EUR'=>60),
);
```

Comment: The issue that I need `name="addon[book]"` because I'll display the name too :)

Comment: @PeeHaa: Thank you. how I could explode the values?

Comment: @PeeHaa: the only thing you should leave in this post is your warning about the input.

Comment: @PeeHaa: I mean you're helping the OP to build a security hole in his site, and although the building of the hole might be interesting, it is dangerous.

Comment: Thanks It works: `$cur = json_decode($_POST['addon']);
echo $cur->{'EUR'};`

Comment: @greg0ire: It is the answer to his question (bad or not). I do state it is not smart to do. And I'm looking for some cheap books atm ;) I'll update my answer to make very clear it is not the best way to go.

Comment: @PeeHaa: ^^ 120 € is quite expensive indeed... and you're right, the faq states that you have to be nice and polite, not that you have to prevent security breaches.

Comment: @greg0ire: Now that I think of it you do have a case. When users ask how to parse html I wouldn't dare telling them to use regex.